# How to push data to a nested Object

Tags: javascript

How can I push another element to the `variables` property from the below object?

```
  var request = {
    "name": "Name",
    "id": 3,
    "rules":[
      {
        "name": "Rule name",
        "tags": [
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "variables":[
              {
                "variable": "var1",
                "matchType": "Regex",
                "value": ".*"
              },
              {
                "variable": "var2",
                "matchType": "Regex",
                "value": ".*"
              }
            ],
            "condition": false,
          },
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "condition": false,
          }
        ],
        "ruleSetId": 3,
      }
    ]
  }
```

For exaple, I need to add `{"variable": "var3", "matchType": "Regex", "value": ".*"}` to the `variables` property from `request` Object...how can I do this?

```
for(i=0;i<duplicates.length; i++) {
  var request = {
    "name": duplicates[i].scope,
    "id": 3,
    "rules":[
      {
        "name": duplicates[i].scope + " " + "OP SDR Sync",
        "tags": [
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "variables":[
              {
              }
            ],
            "condition": false,
          },
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "condition": false,
          }
        ],
        "ruleSetId": 3,
      }
    ]
  }

  request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[0].push({
    "variable":"var3",
    "matchType": "Regex",
    "value": ".*"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to "navigate" properly in your object:

```
request.rules[0].tags[0].variables.push({
  "variable":"var3",
  "matchType": "Regex",
  "value": ".*"
})
```

`request['variables']` will just try to find the `variables` key in root of the `request` object. This key is simply not defined but is nested in your object/array structure.

Comment: Please check my updated question, I get `Error: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.` ... is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: @PavelValeriu Yes. `tags` is an array, thus you have to use `request.rules[0].tags[0].variables`. Also note that `variables` is the array you want to push to, so don't use `[0]` there.

Comment: Now it throws me `Error: Cannot find function push in object [object Object].`

Comment: @PavelValeriu Just copy and paste my answer, this works. You tried `variables[0]` instead of `variables`.

Comment: One more question...can you please tell me why I always get an empty element if I push those values to an empty `variables` object? I added a new question for this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098697/empty-element-is-pushed-to-json-object

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
object = {"variable": "var3", "matchType": "Regex", "value": ".*"};
request.rules[0].tags[0].variables.push(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
request.rules[0].tags[0].variables.push({
  "variable":"var3",
  "matchType": "Regex",
  "value": ".*"
})
```

`variables` is into `tags`, and `tags` is into `rules`.

I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
request.rules[0].tags.variables[0].push({
  "variable":"var3",
  "matchType": "Regex",
  "value": ".*"
});
```

You have to navigate in your array.
Replace the 0 inside the [] to select the item from the array. (0 is first entry, 1 is second entry etc).

Answer (score 0):

dot operator(.) can be used to get the value of a particular object property.

square brackets ([]) can be used to access an element of an array.

Now the answer to your question:

```
request.rules[0].tags[0].variables.push({
"variable": "var3", 
"matchType": "Regex", 
"value": ".*"
});
```

here, `[0]` specifies the first element of your array.